# How to get the sum of the values of the JSON Array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have below the Array that came from the JSON response

```
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 121,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 13,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 232,
    "missedChats": 9
```

I needed the sum of the 'chats and 'missedChats' per website id. I tried using Array.prototype.reduce() like this

```
const chatData =   fetch('https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/tawkto/aA8zqE/4f62624a75da6d1b8dd7f70e53af8d36a1603910/files/webstats.json');
var sum = JSON.parse(chatData).reduce(function(acc, val){
  return acc.chats + val.missedChats;
}, {chats, missedChats: 0});
```

but I get an error like this

```
VM362:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at <anonymous>:4:16
```

Fairly new to JavaScript so any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `console.log(chatData)` after the first line with show you, that `chatData` is not what you thought it was at this point. So, time to go and read up on how `fetch` actually works then.

Comment: if its an array cant you call them in a loop and add them? like `acc[count].chats`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: your fetch might be failing. can you please check? also JSON.parse might not be needed for `https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/tawkto/aA8zqE/4f62624a75da6d1b8dd7f70e53af8d36a1603910/files/webstats.json`

Comment: @Raj yes my fetch function is failing. I used the solution of the accepted answer below. and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch() return a Promise that you need to wait before getting data:

```js
fetch('https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/tawkto/aA8zqE/4f62624a75da6d1b8dd7f70e53af8d36a1603910/files/webstats.json')
    .then(response => {
        response.text().then(data => {
            const json = JSON.parse(data);
            // Process data as json here
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why `response.text()` + `JSON.parse()`?  `fetch().then(response => response.json())`

Comment: Yeah you can go with your solution, my point was just to point that he need to look into his fetch function to resolve his error.

Comment: Looks like the response body is a readable stream and hence the `text()` which again returns a promise that resolves to finally data. good one :)

Answer (score 2):

`fetch()` returns promise. Then parse it into json

```
const chatData = fetch('https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/tawkto/aA8zqE/4f62624a75da6d1b8dd7f70e53af8d36a1603910/files/webstats.json');

chatData.then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(people => {
  //process here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object with keys as `websiteIds` and add up the values using array.reduce like below:

```js
let data = [{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 121,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 13,
    "missedChats": 0
},
{
    "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
    "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "chats": 232,
    "missedChats": 9
}]



let result = data.reduce(function(acc, val){
  if(!acc[val.websiteId]){
     acc[val.websiteId] = { chats: 0, missedChats: 0 };
  }
  acc[val.websiteId].chats += val.chats;
  acc[val.websiteId].missedChats += val.missedChats;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 let data = [{
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000001",
        "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "chats": 121,
        "missedChats": 0
    },
    {
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000002",
        "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "chats": 13,
        "missedChats": 0
    },
    {
        "websiteId": "4f8b36d00000000000000003",
        "date": "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "chats": 232,
        "missedChats": 9
    }];

let group = data.reduce((r, a) => {
 r[a.websiteId] = [...r[a.websiteId] || [], {"missedChats":a.missedChats,"chats":a.chats}];
 return r;
}, {});

console.log(group);
```